# How do I align a button to be inline with the bottom of an adjacent text area?

Tags: html, css, zend-form, alignment

I'm working within zend forms. Currently this is how it looks:

[image]

I want to align the 'Suggest Subtest' button so that it is inline with the bottom of the Subtest text area, like below;

[image]

I've created a jsfiddle with the code that I used; http://jsfiddle.net/g6SV5/

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each "row" a class of formRow with the following CSS:

```
.formRow {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Then style your submit button to be positioned absolutely at the bottom right of each row.

```
submit {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

Live Example here -> http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/vNuZx/1/